# Most efficient way of checking for shared row, column, diagonal?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

In C++ if I have a square array `int board[8][8]` that's filled like this:

```
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 
0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

What's the shortest way to check if any of the 1's share a row, column, or diagonal with another 1?

edit: I said most efficient when I really meant shortest

Comment: That's tiny, only 8 times 8 fields. I would go with the easiest approach first (i.e. just simple looping). It will most likely be fast enough for your usecase.

Comment: What's shortest way to loop through this to check? I'm new to programming, I'd end up doing multiple loops and checking first for rows then for columns then for diagonals (which I still haven't figured out totally) with counts. Is there any easier way?

Comment: Whatever this way is, it has nothing to do with C++. If you really want to ask a question specific to this language (or to any other language for that matter), then it would be appropriate to post your code along with it, and refer to specific issues within this code. Otherwise, it gives the feeling that you're asking others to implement a solution for you.

Comment: Do you just need to return true if another 1 exist on the same row/column/diagonal, or do you also need to return the index?

Comment: The fastest solution is not to use an 8x8 array. Use an int64_t. Then you can construct a 64 element table of int64_t's, one for each position, that has 1's in the positions corresponding to the respective row, column, and diagonals. Checking whether a 1 shares a row, column, or diag with some other 1 is just "anding" with the right table element: 1 instruction on a 64-bit processor.

Comment: just need to return true

Comment: the int64_t suggestion is really interesting though I'm going to try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 x 8 board?  This must be related to chess or something.

Here's a clever way to test if any piece is on hit by the queen (i.e. almost identical to whether a 1 shares a row, column or diagonal with another 1).

```
bool CG_queen::move(File f_to, Rank r_to, File f_from, Rank r_from)
{
    bool canMakeMove = false;

    //Check to see if Queen is moving only by File or only by Rank.
    //aka, only vertically or horizontally.
    if ( f_from == f_to || r_from == r_to )
    {
        canMakeMove = true;
    }

    //Check to see if Queen only moves diagonally.
    if ( abs(f_from - f_to) == abs(r_to - r_from) )
    {
        canMakeMove = true;
    }

    return canMakeMove;
}
```

Comment: Yep am trying to see if a board with 1-8 queens is situated so that no queens threaten each other.

Comment: The above code is gold, then.  It's been tested thousands of times from my Android/iOS chess app (I can PM you a link to the public repository on GitHub, if you want).

Comment: There's an uglier implementation of the exact program you are trying to write on rosetta code, btw.  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/N-Queens#C.2B.2B

Comment: Did not realize you could not PM here. Here's the link, anyhow.  https://github.com/chessgames/play-zone

Comment: Any questions about the project, just let me know.  The project is complete, but the docs (especially the website I just started to document the project and the terrible readme file) need to be updated heavily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bitmask for the rows, columns and diagonals to indicate if there is a 1 on any of them:

```
int rowMask = 0;
int ColumnMask = 0;
int diagonalMask0 = 0;
int diagonalMask1 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        if(board[i][j])
        {
            // test row:
            if(rowMask & (1 << i))
                return true;
            rowMask |= 1 << i; // mark row set

            // test column:
            if(columnMask & (1 << j))
                return true;
            columnMask |= 1 << j; // mark column set

            // test first diagonal:
            if(diagonalMask0 & (1 << (i + j)))
                return true;
            diagonalMask0 |= 1 << (i + j); // mark diagonal set

            // test first diagonal:
            if(diagonalMask1 & (1 << (8 + i - j)))
                return true;
            diagonalMask1 |= 1 << (8 + i - j); // mark diagonal set
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

If there is an element set in a particular row, the bit for that row is tested in rowMask. If it is already set then return true, otherwise set it  using a bitwise OR so other elements can be tested against it. Do likewise for columns and the diagonals.

Comment: thank you, this is definitely the most easy to understand solution for me, but I feel to be fair since I said shortest I should give it to MrPickles

Comment: @AustinMW Thank you very much.  My code above is not actually that hard to understand if you work it out on paper.  I assume the code to test diagonals was hard to understand, but it's really a neat math trick using vector addition (well, subtraction).

Take any square on the board, say 0,0 (top left corner) and 7,7 (bottom right corner).  Subtract the two and take the absolute value and you get if ( 7 == 7)...which is true since the top left corner and the bottom right corner are on the same diagonal.